# Sync end of audio and video in ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, synchronization

I'd like to sync an audio and video file together so that they *end* at the same time. Is there an easy way to do this with ffmpeg?

The only ideas I have are 1) finding the lengths of the two (which is annoying) and delaying the shorter one by the difference between the two lengths, and 2) reversing the two, syncing them, then reversing again. There's got to be a better way...

Answer (score 1):

After finding the lengths of the two and calculating the required delay, you can run

```
ffmpeg -i video -i audio -af "adelay=6500|6500" -c:v copy output
```

Here, both the channels of a stereo audio stream are delayed by 6500 milliseconds i.e. 6.5 seconds. The video stream is copied over without recompression.